# Magento2: variable email address, order ID, product ID

Tags: magento2, checkout, review

I need to set up a script of trusted reviews, which will send an e-mail message to the client requesting an opinion after each order.

After configure script I need to put in `success.phtml` ( last step checkout with confirmation order).

**Here is instruction:**

https://www.ceneo.pl/poradniki/Podrecznik-integracji-ZO-platformy

**From text:**

"UNIWERSALNA INSTRUKCJA INSTALACJI SKRYPTU ZAUFANYCH OPINII"

Script in `success.phtml`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

ceneo_client_email = ‘customer email address’;

ceneo_order_id = ‘order id’;

             ceneo_shop_product_ids =‘product ID’;

   ceneo_work_days_to_send_questionnaire = 3;

               </script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.ceneo.pl/transactions/track/v2/script.js?accountGuid=XXXXXXXX">

</script>
```

How should I configure this script (what variables should I put in `‘’` tags) to display in `‘’` the data that script required?

@Update Herve,
really thank you for your time. I have install your module and configure all according to your instrucion.

@ Herve update 2
Now code in `success.phtml` looks ok, now I not get any issue after place order:
[image]

But still when I try test work script on ceneo then get issue:

- Positive verification of the script failed. Check if it is installed
  correctly or contact us at sbt@ceneo.pl

Comment: You're using typographical quotes (`‘’`) instead of straight ASCII quotes (`'`) in your code. That's not going to work.

Comment: I put script from https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/mbsorderanalytics/src/master/ is correct in (')

Comment: You bar comment misses an character / to be replaced by */

Comment: Herve, once again thank you for your reply. I am glad that there are people like you who want to help! Can you explain me more what you mean  "bar comment misses an character / to be replaced by */"

Answer (score 1):

I have written a module tonight that should implement your analytics.

The code consists in 2 parts:

- a module that gives your all the data your analytics code needs
- the success.phtml template in your theme to be customised to have your analytics code

the full code is available at:
https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/mbsorderanalytics/src/master/

It would be tricky to come up with some explanations to describe a solution and therefore I allow myself to give you a working solution that we can improve if needed using the community feedback.

Comment: Herve, I have update my topic.

Comment: Herve, can you please check it for us? Because we have any issue with this module. I hope you can help solve issue for us. Thanks

Comment: Reading the update you made, it seems the issue you have is still the same whereby your comment is missing a valid end: quick fix is to remove the comment you have.

Comment: Herve, I have again update2 my topic.